# Validar Datepicker que contém somente data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, validação, jquery.validate, asp.net-mvc

Utilizo o Asp.Net Core MVC (Razor + Jquery Validate + Unobtrusive). Exibo em um Datepicker somente a parte da data de um campo DateTime através do seguinte código em minha ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* preenchimento obrigatório")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Data { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Porém, em minha view, ao digitar o conteúdo do campo com uma data válida, obtenho a mensagem de erro *"Please enter a valid date."*

Quando retirada a data annotation *[DataType(DataType.Date)]* e exibida a parte de hora, a validação funciona corretamente, logo **não é problema de localização**

Também já a adicionei a seguinte data annotation a ViewModel, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Não tenho certeza, mas pelo que me parece o problema está na validação unobtrusiva que parece não se comportar direito com inputs que exibam somente a parte da data.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta e veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505773/custom-date-format-validation-with-jquery-datepicker-cant-get-rid-of-us-date-v

Answer (score 0):

Acrescente isso, deve resolver:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time, UIHint("Time")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```